# Wrap background color around text aligned right

Tags: html, css

**What I'm trying to do**:

I'm trying to achieve the following result:

```css
div {
  text-align: right;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>abc</span><br/>
  <span>Hello world this is some text</span><br />
  <span>hello world</span>
</div>
```

However, in the above example, I have split my lines up individually, as I have contained each line in a separate `span`.

I want to achieve the same (or similar) result as above by using a `width` to define when a new line should start/end, rather than containing each new line in its own `span`.

**What I've tried:**

I've tried doing the following:

```css
div {
  text-align: right;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  width: 200px; /* Width to define where line break should appear */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>abc</span><br/>
  <span>Hello world this is some text hello world</span>
</div>
```

However, in the above example, the black background covers a "block" rather than wrapping around each line of text.

So, how do I get my second snippet to act in the same way as the first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add another wrapper that you keep inline:

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height:1; /*remove the gap*/
  color: #fff;
  width: 200px; /* Width to define where line break should appear */
}
span > span {
  display:inline;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: right;">
  <span><span>abc</span></span><br>
  <span><span>Hello world this is some text hello world</span></span>
</div>
```

You can also adjust padding and keep the default line-height:

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  width: 200px; /* Width to define where line break should appear */
}
span > span {
  display:inline;
  background: #000;
  padding:2px 0;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: right;">
  <span><span>abc</span></span><br>
  <span><span>Hello world this is some text hello world</span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Is there any way to remove the line gaps between each line though?

Comment: @NickParsons yes by adjusting line-height, check the update

Comment: @NickParsons added another way to control the gap

Answer (score 1):

Another solution without using a span inside a span.

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  width: 200px; /* Width to define where line break should appear */
  text-align: right;
  line-height: 2;
}
.txt {
  display:inline;
  background: black;
  padding:2px 0;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: right;">
  <div class="container">
    <span class="txt">Hello world this is some text hello world. Hello world this is some text hello world. </span>
  </div>
</div>
```