# What is the proper way to write conditional statement inside flatMap with Promise.all in Javascript

Tags: javascript, promise, flatmap, promise.all

I am working on a `flatMap` with `Promise.all`; there are two condition inside `flatMap`, the `originalObj` is for checking whether `originalObj.state` is false or not, then implement the `insertRealStartTime`, and in every `event`, I will implement the `Event.updateMany` regardless the condition, and I want to return it as well because the return of `Events.updateMany()` told me whether or not the update is a success.

```js
function async foo(){
  const eventPromises = events.flatMap(async (event) => {
      if (event.state.matchPhase == "1H") {
        // simpleQuery is async function
        const originalObj = await simpleQuery({ id: event.id });
        if (originalObj.state == false) {
          // insertRealStartTime is async function
          await insertRealStartTime(event.id);
        }
      }
      // Event.updateMany is async function
      await Events.updateMany(
        { ...event, expireAt: event["startTime"] },
      );
    }
  );
  const all = await Promise.all(eventPromises);
  console.log(all)
}
```

I got an array of `undefined` in `console.log(all)`; I think I probably shouldn't use `await` inside `flatMap` because it lost the meaning of using `Promise.all`; however, how should I deal with all these if-statement to make sure the async function will execute base on the if-statement with `Promise.all`?

Comment: You need to `return` from the flatMap callback, although `async` functions within a `flatMap` callback doesn't really work (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53422511/wrap-background-color-around-text-aligned-right)). Seems like you might just want `.map()`.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see `flatMap` from the link, can you post an answer on how I can correct it to `.map()`? @NickParsons

Comment: Sorry, I thought I edited my previous comment to correct the link, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74959270/5648954) is the link I was supposed to send.  But to me, it looks like you want to do `return insertRealStartTime(event.id);` and `return Events.updateMany(...)` (instead of `await`), and change `.flatMap()` to be `.map()`

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76880635/what-is-the-proper-way-to-write-conditional-statement-inside-flatmap-with-promis#comment135533880_76880635) @TungTung Instead of `.flatMap(async ...)`, you can use `.flat().map(async ...)`

Comment: If I had two return inside `.map()`, will it be only returning only `insertRealStartTime(event.id)` but missed `Events.updateMany(...)` when fulfilling all condition? @NickParsons

Comment: Except for the change to `.flat().map()` do I need to change any things? Do you mind adding an answer to show the corrected code? @jsejcksn

Comment: @TungTung That's all you need to fix the `flatMap` problem, but it won't address your "array of undefined" problem — you never `return` anything from the callback function: did you intend to (and, if so, what)?

Comment: The problem is if I try to change all `await` to `return`, it will only return the first async function, so may I ask what can I `return` things and can execute all fulfilled condition function in `.map`? @jsejcksn

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76880635/what-is-the-proper-way-to-write-conditional-statement-inside-flatmap-with-promis?noredirect=1#comment135534083_76880635) @TungTung Don't _remove_ the `await` keywords and _replace_ them with `return`. Just `return` the value that you want to at the end of the function. If you don't need to return a value, then the array will always be full of `undefined`. Only you can tell us if you want to `return` something: do you? If so, what value do you want to return each time the callback is invoked?

Comment: I want to return `await Events.updateMany()`, so should I just change the `await` to `return` in `await Events.updateMany()`? @jsejcksn

Comment: It is not really clear what you want those promises to resolve to. I imagine that if `event.state.matchPhase` is "1H", you would want `originalObj` to be in your final array (is that what you expect?), but what if `event.state.matchPhase` is something else, then what do you expect to get in your final array? Do `insertRealStartTime` or `updateMany` resolve to some value that you need? If so, you currently ignore those values. Lots of clarification is needed about your expected array.

Comment: I have added the clarification to the question, thank you. @trincot

Comment: What is the type of `events`? What is the desired type of `all`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `flatMap` callback does not have a `return` statement, so the promises returned by those `async` calls will resolve to `undefined`.

As you want the get the values that the `updateMany()` promises resolve to, you should return those.

There are at least two ways to do that:

1. Get the value that `await Events.updateMany()` evaluates to, and then return it (You would of course add the argument):

   ```
   const success = await Events.updateMany();
   return success;
   ```
2. Return the promise returned by `Events.updateMany()`:

   ```
   return Events.updateMany();
   ```

Either works.

Not a problem, but if the callback returns a promise (as is your case), there is no reason to use `flatMap`. `flatMap` would be useful if you expect **arrays** as return values for the callback, but that is impossible with `async` callbacks -- they always return promise objects. So you can just use `map`.

With some other updates to your code, you get this:

```
function async foo() {
  const eventPromises = events.map(async (event) => {
      if (event.state.matchPhase == "1H") {
        // You can use destructuring here, as you're only interested in the state property
        const {state} = await simpleQuery({ id: event.id });
        if (!state) { // Use NOT operator
          await insertRealStartTime(event.id);
        }
      }
      // Return the promise
      return Events.updateMany(
        { ...event, expireAt: event.startTime }
      );
    }
  );
  const all = await Promise.all(eventPromises);
  console.log(all);
  return all; // Provide the caller something to work with...
}
```